# Generate report from Google Analytics with specific URLs and monthly pageviews?

Tags: google-analytics

I have been asked to track several existing pages (about 50 in total) and track monthly page views.

So far in GA I have not been able to find an automated and quick way to do this. What GA does quite easily is let you filter based on URL but if I have to do this manually each time I am going to get old, fast.

Ideally want I want to be able to do is create a custom report that spits out monthly page views for select URLs.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com  We do a lot of custom applications such as this at an very affordable price.  We could set you up with an interface where you control the different urls.  Report could be served in a variety of formats (html on your page, pdf, etc).